# Magento custom attribute for shipping address not saving to sales order grid in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, sales-order, custom-attributes, shipping-address

I have added a custom field in checkout page shipping address, it is saving in the database, but not displaying sales orders admin section in magento2.
but it is saving to billing address section.

Can anyone help me how to resolve this?

Please find the screenshot below:

[enter link description here](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3380883/30863a9f641c26a457c2f31625394a51)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can save your custom field in sales_order_grid using di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_field" xsi:type="string">sales_order.custom_field</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```